# Can't boot into Windows 10 after latest updating Mac OS to 10.15.4

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I had Windows 10 installed, and everything was working great.
Updating my Mac OS installation to Mojave caused Bluetooth on my Mac to not work with any other devices except my iPhone.

I was hoping 10.15.4 would fix my Mac. I updated, and now I cannot boot into Windows 10. It either restarts, or it goes to a screen giving me the choice of Advanced Repair options or trying to continue to boot (which results in restarting).

Mac OS of course, still seems to work fine. How can I boot into Windows 10 again ?

Comment: Windows boot doesn’t really care about if macOS can use Bluetooth. Isn’t this really about fixing windows 10 os not booting? If so, I can migrate this to super user

Comment: It is about fixing Windows 10 not booting. I think the question should remain here as well, because Bootcamp installed via Mac OS, and most Mac users would be over here.

Comment: And what happens if you let Windows 10 repair itself?

Comment: @SteveChambers it doesn’t. The same problem comes back. Now after a few attempts at booting it’s randomly booted into windows without error.

Comment: Have you tried recreating the boot files?

Comment: @DavidAnderson no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recreating the Windows boot files. This answer assumes you are UEFI booting Windows 10.

To rebuild the boot files you need to boot to Windows Recover Environment (WRE) of from a Windows installation flash drive. If you can boot to Windows and have a properly working WRE, then restart Windows while holding down the shift key. You will need to navigate to where you can open a Command Prompt window. Otherwise, to create a Windows 10 installation flash drive and then open a Command Prompt window, follow the steps below.

### Create a Windows 10 Flash Drive Installer

1. Download the [latest Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
2. ExFAT format a flash drive using the MBR partition scheme.
3. Mount and copy all the files from the ISO to the flash drive.
4. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software.
5. Copy the Windows Support Software to the flash drive.
6. Boot from the flash drive.
7. Proceed as if you are installing Windows until asked for a product key.
8. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination to open a Command Prompt window.

### Rebuild Boot Files

Once you have a Command Prompt window open, enter the following commands.

Mount the EFI volume and assign to drive `S:`.

```
mountvol s: /s
```

Remove any previous backup. If no previous backup exists, then expect error messages to appear.

```
rd /s /q s:\efi\Microsoft.old
rd /s /q s:\efi\boot.old
```

Backup existing files by renaming folders.

```
ren s:\efi\Microsoft Microsoft.old
ren s:\efi\Boot Boot.old
```

Determine the existing drive letters. Determine by inspection the drive letter of the main Windows volume. Usually, this is drive `C:`. If you are using a different drive letter, then make the appropriate substitutions in the subsequent commands.

```
echo list vol | diskpart
```

Create new boot files.

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s s: /f UEFI
```

Delete the Boot Configuration Data file (BCD) created in the previous step.

```
del s:\efi\microsoft\boot\bcd
```

Rebuild the BCD. Answer yes to any questions.

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Close the window.

```
exit
```

### References

- [Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues)
- [REAgentC command-line options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options)
- [BCDBoot Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di)
- [mountvol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't verify if its correct or not because Windows seems to have arbitrarily decided to boot now. But I'm marking it as correct so other people can try it if they have the same problem.

Comment: Actually the problem has returned. Arbitrarily boots into Windows either succeed or fail. Windows is unable to automatically repair or diagnose the problem when I choose advanced repair options. I think trying this is risky, because the problem seems to be with something Mac OS is doing (not every time)

Comment: To repair windows you usually have to do this offline. This means you need to boot to a small version of windows that is running from a RAM drive. You have yet to do this which may be why you have failed to repair Windows.

Comment: I’m narrowing down the cause - it’s not random - I’m thinking launching specific software on OS X causes the problem.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Mac OS - 10.15.4 has many bugs which are not only bricking macs but causing problems like mine.

Comment: macOS has nothing to do with Windows. Microsoft Windows installs on a Mac the same as any ordinary PC. The instruction given in my  answer would apply regardless if you own a Mac or some other brand computer.

Comment: - although Windows and Mac OS are on different volumes / partitions, there are some thing related to booting that are shared. Mac OS seems to be messing with some setting to arbitrarily you can’t boot into Windows.

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the NVRAM. Resetting the NVRAM causes instability.